# JQuery $.html makes div empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a website mostly to get better at coding but I recently got into problem which I can't figure out how to solve.

Code:

```
$("#user-admin-notification-area").blur(function() {
   alert(events[__event].text);
   if(this.value == '')
      $ePreview.html(events[__event].text);
   $ePreview.html(this.value);
});
```

Code above sets `$ePreview` html to empty string instead of actual expected html while alert gives proper output... I tested same code in console but there it's ok. (by same code I mean `$ePreview.html(events[__event].text)`.

`Events`'s value:

```
[
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "pozostały czas",
        "start": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
        "end": "2016-01-31 23:59:59",
        "text": "<b>Uwaga!</b> Jeszcze <span data-end=\"1451606399\" data-reload=\"false\"></span> do końca składania zgłoszeń! Śpiesz się!",
        "type": "5",
        "closeable": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "test",
        "start": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
        "end": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
        "text": "I should NOT be displayed! :)",
        "type": "5",
        "closeable": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "test #2",
        "start": "2015-11-08 23:59:59",
        "end": "2015-11-30 23:59:59",
        "text": "Hi m8!",
        "type": "5",
        "closeable": "0"
    }
]
```

Comment: So the `alert(event);` is giving you a error or `alert(events[event]);` ?

Comment: @EndritShala none of these any more. Please look at edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't make sense. If `this.value` is empty, then you set the html to be `events[__event].text`, but then you set back the empty value in the next line (**`$ePreview.html(this.value);`**). It should be something like:

```
$("#user-admin-notification-area").blur(function() {
   alert(events[__event].text);
   if(this.value == '')
      $ePreview.html(events[__event].text); 
   else 
      $ePreview.html(this.value);
});
```